# Render template in Flask from ajax call

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, templates, flask

Having a tough time with this. I'm sending some data via Ajax to my Flask server route where it is being processed, with hopes to then render a new template with the processed data. The data seems to be flowing fine from my Javascript to my Flask server. (I am using JSGlue for Flask.url_for.) But as soon as it gets to "return render_template" it just dies. I get no traceback errors or anything. I've tried print() and console.log all over the place to get some kind of idea of what is killing it, but so far I've come up empty. Am I missing something obvious?

**mypage.js**

```
let c_list = [1,2,3....];

    $.ajax({
        url: Flask.url_for('get_genres'),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(c_list),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
```

**init.py**

```
@app.route('/get_genres', methods=["GET", "POST"]
def get_genres():
    if request.method == "POST":
        categories = request.json
        c = Querybuilder()
        genres = c.genres_from_c(categories)
        return render_template("genres.html", genres=genres)
```

**index.html**

```
<head>

    {{ JSGlue.include() }}
</head>

<body>

    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

**genres.html**

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block body %}
<div class="genre_list">
    {% for genre in genres %}
    <a href="#" src="{{ genres[genre] }}" class="unclicked" onclick="toggleClicked(this)">
        <p>{{ genre }}</p></a>
    {% endfor %}
    <a href="#" onclick="getGenreId()">NEXT</a>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: you defined `methods=["GET"]` - so it can't get `POST` - you need `methods=["GET", "POST"]`

Comment: did you generate `mypage.js` with `Flask` template ? If not then you can't use `Flask.url_for('get_genres')`. And if you generate it with `Flask` tempalte then maybe it should use `{{ url_for(...) }}`

Comment: 1. Your route need to accept POST 2. If your are returning html from post request,  it's more normal to return section on page to be redrawn not whole page.  then (if using JQuery) do something like `$("#ajaxgenerated").html(data);` in callback function on *success*

Comment: Edited to include the "POST". That's in my code, not sure why I removed it when typing this question out. It still does not work even with it. Also, I am using JSGlue which allows Flask.url_for and I've tested it to be working. Any other ideas? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

After A LOT of digging around, I finally managed to find a solution to this issue. Adding a success function to the ajax call that redirects to another route.

**mypage.js**

```
$.ajax({
        url: Flask.url_for('genre_picks'),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(genres),
        success: function(response) {
            window.location.href = response.redirect
        }
    });
```

****init****

```
@app.route('/genre_picks', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def genre_picks():
    if request.method == "POST":
        genres = request.json
        return jsonify({'redirect': url_for("example", path=genres)})

@app.route('/example/<path>')
def example(path):
    genres = path
    return render_template("example.html", genres=genres)
```

Comment: Your suggested solution makes little sense. Why undertake an Ajax call in order to then receive on client side a redirect url that you then execute to make a fresh full-page server-side request?

Comment: My main reasoning was because I didn't want the variables to be present in the url when the page renders. I wanted to keep it as mysite.me/example, rather than mysite.me/example?long_string_of_variables_...... I couldn't find any other solution to this in my searching.